# Firebase_admob in flutter wrong job on Ios device

Tags: ios, flutter

I use rxDart package in my project, and get the data from the server as streams, added firebase_admob and show ads in app, but when the advertisement on the banner changes, then my streams start automatically.
Why so?

I tried FirebaseAdMob call from different places

```
@override
initState() {
super.initState();
bloc.loginUser();
bloc.onPositionChanged();
bloc.inAnimate.add(false);
bloc.inMapZoom.add(18.0);
bloc.inScreenVisible.add(Screen.main);
bloc.pushNotification();
FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
bloc.adsBanner();
}

StreamBuilder<ReportData>(
        stream: bloc.outAllVicinity,
        builder: (context, vicinitySnapshot) {
          if (vicinitySnapshot.hasData) {
            if (vicinitySnapshot.data != null) {
              _setReportsList(vicinitySnapshot.data);
              return Positioned(
                  top: 8.0,
                  child: Text(("all reports 
${vicinitySnapshot.data.data.length}")));
            } else {
              return Positioned(
                  top: 8.0,
                  child: Text(("${vicinitySnapshot.data.error} "
                      )));
            }
          }
          if (vicinitySnapshot.error != null) {
            return Positioned(
                top: 8.0, child: Text("Some trouble in 
outAllVicinity"));
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
      StreamBuilder<ReportData>(
        stream: bloc.outInVicinity,
        builder: (context, inVicinitySnapshot) {
          if (inVicinitySnapshot.hasData) {
            _setReportsListFindQuest(inVicinitySnapshot.data);
            return Positioned(
                top: 20.0,
                child: Text((" invicinity reports 
${inVicinitySnapshot.data.data.length} "
                    "\n markers count ${markers.length}")));
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
```

Every time when advertisement changes, data automatically comes to me from streams.